# Content Inset with Custom Drawable Scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, listviewitem, android-relativelayout

I have a ListView with custom items defined in a relativeLayout, which includes an imageView with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and a custom vector drawable as a source, which schematically looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
+    solid area              | some picture +
+-------------------------------------------+
```

The issue is when I turn to the landscape mode the image gets scaled up (to mach the parent's width), however keeping the aspect ratio the height is increased, as well.

Ideally I would like to define a Content Inset (as I know it from iOS), so that the solid area above gets stretched to match the new width, and the 'some picture'-area is kept at the same aspect ratio. All in all I the scaling would happen such that the height of the image (and hence of the whole listView item) is kept the same.

Comment: try a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` object passed to `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your reply -- not really sure which way to go? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: if you want custom scaling you need to draw your stuff in a custom `Shape#draw` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the solid area to stretch by using a `LinearLayout` with a layout *weight* in the child width.  To make this work, you should assign a fixed width to the `ImageView`.

Also, the `adjustViewBounds` attribute on the `ImageView` will help to maintain the correct aspect ratio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- this can be any view or view group, the layout params are the important part-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ...
        />

    <!-- set this to an absolute width that will be the same for portrait & landscape -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        ...
        />

</LinearLayout>
```